# Backward differences Newton Polynomials question

Tags: polynomials

Use Newton's backward-difference formula to construct interpolating polynomials of degree
one, two, and three for the following data.

f (-1/3) if f(-0.75) = -0.07181250, f(-O.5) = -0.02475000, f(-0.25) =
0.33493750, f(0) = 1.10100000

Is my solution alright?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your backward divided difference calculations are correct.

The columns below are $f(x), 1^{st}-DD, 2^{nd}-DD, 3^{rd}-DD$ and compare your results to the last row:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -0.0718125 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -0.02475 & 0.18825 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.334938 & 1.43875 & 2.501 & 0 \\
 1.101 & 3.06425 & 3.251 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Recall that you will be using that last row of values for the actual degree one, two and three polynomials.

Comment: Are P1 and P2 and P3 correct?

Comment: @user3543012: Yes, your results are correct. regards